# Алгоритм расположения наклеек на кубике Рубика произвольного размера

Tags: алгоритм, любой-язык

[image: Пример поворота граней R U R']
Допустим есть кубик рубика произвольного размера NxNxN.

На входе имеем начальное положение блока A(Xa, Ya, Za), конечное положение B(Xb, Yb, Zb) и углы вращения вокруг трёх осей, на которые блок повернулся в процессе перемещения... Траектория перемещения может быть очень запутанной и нам не интересна. Эти входные данные абсолютно однозначно определяют конечное состояние одного из блоков (положение и разворот). Пытаюсь вывести алгоритм который по входным данным возвратит куда переместилась наклейка на данном блоке.

Рассмотрим пример по картинке:

Цифрой 1 обозначим начальное положение блока A(0, 2, 2).
Цифрой 2 - конечное положение блока B(2, 2, 0).
Для лучшего понимания можно добавить что второе положение из первого в данном случае мы получили прокрутив: (R U R') (описание снизу) Потому имеем повороты вокруг трёх осей R(-90, 90, 0) (т.е. при повороте R блок 1 не менял положения, при U повернулся вокруг Y по часовой, при R' - вокруг X против часовой).

*На выходе нужно вычислить, что если белая наклейка в исходном положении была сверху, то в конечном стала спереди, соответственно оранжевая была слева, стала сверху, а синяя была сзади, стала справа*

**Важно** что какие были повороты мы не знаем, на входе их нет, а к конечной позиции можно прийти другим путём и иметь другие повороты, хотя внешне ничего не изменится (другие блоки будут на других местах, но они нам не интересны), потому как их задействовать в алгоритме пока не ясно, но они необходимы!
Т.е. при цепочке, например (L F) мы окажемся в том же положении, так же развёрнуты, но развороты будут на входе R(90, 0, 90), а при цепочке (L2 D R) тоже достигнем нужного положенияи разворота, но развороты будут R(90, -90, 0).

**Необходим свежий взгляд со стороны, что-то я немного подзавис!**

PS:

1. **Классическая запись вращений:** **U**p, **D**own, **L**eft, **R**ight, **F**ront, **B**ack начальные буквы названий сторон для поворота по часовой стрелке (если она находится перед нами) и с апострофом, например R' для поворота против часовой стрелки, а так же с 2, например R2 для поворота на 180 градусов.
2. **Классическое расположение цветов**: **F** - зеленый, **U** - белый, **B** - синий, **R** - красный, **L** - оранжевый, **D** - жёлтый.
3. Работа ведётся с двухмерной разметкой кубика.

   [image: Двухмерная разметка кубика]

**Информация к размышлению:** только мне кажется, что тут какая-то логическая ошибка?
Рассмотрим несколько простых примеров(в каждом примере следим за передним-правым-верхним углом):

1. Прокручиваем **F2 L2**
   Имеем вектор разворота R(180, 0, 180), По оси Y он не поворачивался, но если бы мы не знали как он был туда поставлен, могли бы с уверенностью сказать поворотом вокруг Y на 180!
2. Прокручиваем **R B L F**
   Наблюдаемый кубик возвращается в исходное положение, т.е. разница векторов координат (0, 0, 0), развороты вокруг осей сокращаются и тоже получаем R(0, 0, 0). Т.е. вообще никакой информации, но кубик развёрнут по часовой стрелке!
3. Прокручиваем **F' L' B' R'**
   Наблюдаемый кубик возвращается в исходное положение, т.е. разница векторов координат (0, 0, 0), развороты вокруг осей так же сокращаются и тоже получаем R(0, 0, 0). Т.е. снова вообще никакой информации, но кубик развёрнут уже против часовой стрелки!

Comment: Укажите желаемый язык программирования в метках, иначе вы скорее всего не получите ответ.

Comment: @Bharata с какой целью алгоритм привязывать к яп? Я же не прошу это реализовать, просто вывести формулу можно... Язык абсолютно любой

Comment: Когда я отвечаю на вопросы, то выбираю нужную мне метку и отвечаю. Не искать же мне среди всех вопросов нужные. А здесь я случайно сегодня в общем потоке. У вас будет больше возможностей получения правильного ответа. Ваш вопрос мне нравится -вот и советую вам. ;-)

Comment: Статья https://habr.com/post/173131/, создается на c# с OpenGL

Comment: @Александр Кудрявцев это не то, это я уже читал. там только 3D, оно уже в классах отлажено и работает. В 3D мы задали блок и при его поворотах и перемещениях нам не нужно следить за цветами граней, они сами собой перемещаются, т.к. являются частью объекта... Я пытаюсь реализовать двухмерную его развёртку: https://i.imgur.com/SDSXrjd.png  
Для этого понадобилось узнать местоположение стикеров в данный момент, т.к. 1 элемент проецируется в несколько различных мест, смотри, например блок номер 17

Comment: Посмотреть бы на тот код, с которым у вас всё остановилось.

Comment: @sanmai временная заплатка: http://pygments.org/demo/6752918/
работает, если поворот одновременно только вокруг одной из осей, если две или три, то уже не всегда работает

Comment: Скорее всего тут нужен поиск в ширину. Прописать комбинации, и разворачивать поиск в ширину, до тех пор пока не будет достигнута нужная позиция. 6 сторон поворачиваются влево или вправо - это 12 комбинаций за одну итерацию.

Comment: @nick_n_a скорее всего я как-то не правильно считаю угол поворота, обрати внимание на "Информацию к размышлению"  пункты 2 и 3. У нас там получаются одинаковые данные на входе и разные на выходе, такого не должно быть в принципе, т.к. положение в пространстве и угол разворота должны однозначно определять объект

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Давайте попробуем составить алгоритм. Я предлагаю алгоритм — поиск в ширину.

1. Определим **обьект кубика**. У куба 6 сторон. 6 цветов. Каждая сторона — 9 элементов. Давайте куб опишем массивом на 54 (`6 × 9 = 54`) элемента. Тогда конечная цель — чтобы каждые 9 элементов были равны. Давайте "нарисуем" модель.

   ```
             18 19 20
             21 22 23
             24 25 26
   0  1  2   9  10 11  36 37 38   45 46 47
   3  4  5   12 13 14  39 40 41   48 49 50
   6  7  8   15 16 17  42 43 44   51 52 53
             27 28 29
             30 31 32
             33 34 35
   ```
2. Давайте определим **действия**, которые можно делать с кубиком. И так, у нас есть 6 граней, каждую сторону можно вращать вокруг собственной оси в обе стороны.  Итого, у нас есть `6 × 2 = 12` действий. Нужно описать все 12 действий. Я опишу вам одно, остальные — самостоятельно. Для описания — элементы будут меняться местами. Для наглядности — давайте вращать грань 9-17 вокруг себя, тогда я парами указываю элементы, которые поменяются местами:

   ```
               18     19    20
               21     22    23
               24-36  25-39 26-42
   0  1  2-26  9-11  10-14 11-17    36-29  37 38   45 46 47
   3  4  5-25  12-10  13    14-16    39-28  40 41   48 49 50
   6  7  8-24  15-9   16-12 17-15    42-27  43 44   51 52 53
               27-2   28-5  29-8
               30     31     32
               33     34     35
   ```

В виде пар это будет вид

> 24-36,25-39,26-42, 2-26, 9-11,10-14,11-17,36-29,5-25, 12-10, 
>   14-16,39-28, 8-24, 15-9,16-12,17-15,42-27,27-2 ,28-5,  29-8

Вышло 20-ть пар. 12 + 8 = 20. Если пары поменять местами — будет вращение в противоположную сторону. Таких пар по 20 штук должно быть 12 вариантов. Я показываю один.

Попробую описать вращение рисунков в 3D. Вращение будет происходить только для 9 элементов, с 9-того по 17 включая 13. Остальные вращаться не будут, если это 2D проекция, а уже переводя это в 3D проекцию, получим больше вариантов.

Упакованый вариант разворота
 `a[i] = (a[i] & 7) + ((a[i] + 8) & (8+16))` и влево `a[i] = (a[i] & 7) + ((a[i] - 8) & (24))` применить это для 9 елементов после перестановок. Тогда `(a[i] & 24) = {0,8,16,24}` в зависимости от разворота.

Вариант разворота простой с and `x.size = (x.side+1)&3` или `x.size = (x.side-1)&3`

Вариант разворота усложнённый `if (x.size=3) x.size = 0; else x.size++` или  `if (x.size=0) x.size = 3; else x.size--`

UPD **Важно:** при операции вращения, лучше создавать отдельный массив, поскольку можно "случайно" присвоить два раза одну ячейку. Например при в 11 мы присвоили 9, а в 17 присваиваем 11 — и получаем "сбой", поэтому слева от присваивания должен быть исходный массив, а справа (куда приваиваем) — дубликат исходного массива.

**ИТОГ:** делаем 20 операций перестановки, потом 9-операций 2D вращения, при этом один из 9 — центральный элемент, который не вошёл в 20.

3. Имея обьект кубика, давайте определим **конечное условие**: это будет о[0]=o[1]=…=o[8], о[9]=o[10]=…=o[17], …, т.е. все каждые 9 элементов массива должны быть равны.
4. Теперь, когда у нас есть "обьект", то мы создаём массив обьектов, и начинаем строить дерево. Каждый новый уровень, добавляет по несколько элементов в массив. Нужно это для того, чтоб убрать "лишнии" движения, и найти решение используя поиск в ширину.

   Делаем структуру (№итерации, №действия(1-12), №элемента, который привёл к появлению даного, "обьект"(массив на 54))
     Далее строим 1-вую итерацию, т.е. цикл на 12 перестановок граней, получаем

   ```
    a[0]=(0,0,0,-1,obj),a[1]=(1,1,0,obj),a[2]=(1,2,0,obj),a[3]=(1,3,0,obj),
    a[4]=(1,4,0,obj)..a[12]=(1,12,0,obj);
   ```

   Каждый обьект, проверяем условие [3]. Делаем 2-рую итерацию. Тут уже возникнет проблема. Начнут появляться дубли. Дубли образуются тогда, когда мы одну и ту же грань вращаем сначала влево, а потом на 2-й итерации, её же вправо. Можно придумать как алгоритмически этого избежать, но сложно. Кроме того, нужно ещё фильтровать 4-х кратное вращение и т.д., поэтому проще — просто фильтровать дубли. Т.е, как по мне — то проще — проверять с добавлением нового элемента массива — нет ли дублей ниже, в элементах `a[0]…a[n]` (`a[12]`). Вторая итерация принесёт `12 × 12 = 144` элемента, но половина — будут точно дубли. Поэтому будет где-то +72 элемента. Для упрощения сделаем так. Второй уровень будет иметь примерно такой вид

   ```
    a[0]=(0,0,0,-1,obj),a[1]=(1,1,0,obj),a[2]=(1,2,0,obj),a[3]=(1,3,0,obj),
    a[4]=(1,4,0,obj)..a[12]=(1,12,0,obj);
    a[13]=(2,1,1,obj),a[14]=(2,1,2,obj)...a[84]=(2,12,6,obj)
   ```

За тем повторяем итерации, до тех пор, пока решение не будет найдено (т.е. условие [3] не будет выполнено. По массиву можно будет установить ход событий (т.е. если ответ 84, то 84 породил элемент 6, который породил элемент 0. в элементе 6, указано куда вращали).

---

P.S. При 3D рендеринге, будет `6 × 4 = 24` положения рисунка. Если рендеринг будет плавным, то нужно будет из одного из 24 положений плавно переходить к другому. Квадрат можно наклеить на куб 4-мя вариантами.

У куба 6 сторон, поэтому для 3D — у вас 24 вариата. Но если оперировать 24-мя вариантами, то задача вращения усложняется, т.к. прийдётся вращать все 20-ть элементов (20 пар из [2]). Проще вращать 9-елементов 4-мя комбинациями, а +6 комбинаций добавить на фазе рендеринга в 3Д (6- в зависимости на какой стороне куба мы оказались). Т.е. при рендеринге будет `realside = side+ kubeside* 4` где `size` — значение одного из 54 елементов, `size` в пределах `[0..3]`, а `kubeside` в пределах `[0..5]` — означает на какой стороне куба мы находимся. После проецирование на 2D проскость, может оказаться что эти 24 варианта перешли в 12 или меньше, но именно цифра 24 дает основу, которая "убирает" хаос. Т.е. задаёт порядок такой, что грань не может быть развёрнута "не туда".

Мне показалось что про 24 комбинации не совсем понятно. Попробую нарисовать

```
        ^ ^ ^
        < ^ v
        > > > 
 < ^ >  ^ ^ >  ^ ^ ^  > > >
 < v >  v v >  ^ < <  < ^ v
 < v >  ^ ^ v  < < <  v v v
        < < >
        ^ ^ >
        V V V
```

это комбинация из 4-х положений на двухмерке. Она домножится на 6 вариантов, потому что кажую из 6 сторон, прийдётся рендерить на 3D 6-ю способами. А 3D модель будет… надо подумать в чём можно быстро нарисовать… Имеется ввиду что комбинация `0..53 × 4 варианта развотота × 6 вариантов нахожнения на стороне` дадут всегда однозначно 3D-вектор. `0..53`  даст однозначно 3D координату вектора, а 24 (`4 × 6`) даёт разворот, направление вектора трехмерное. Т.е. можно составить массив на 54 координаты, и на 24 вектора направлености — и  3D преобразование гладко пройдет.

Расписываю 24. В 2D у нас будет 4-ре плоских вектора: 0, 90, 180, 270 (поворот в плоскости XY).

В 3Д наложатся такие повороты (XY, XZ, YZ).

```
  ^y           2 (0,0,90)
  0(0,270,0)   1 (0,0,0)   4(0,90,0)  5(0,0,180)
               3 (0,0,270)        --x>
```

Надеюсь, я правильно вектора поворота в градусах расписал. Добавив (0, 90, 180, 270) в первую координату вращения XY — получим 24 комбинации разворота.

5-тый (спинка) — спорный, если его развернуть на 180 по XZ и ещёраз на 180 по YZ — то мы получим "исходное положение обьекта" в почти "зеркальном виде".  `5(0,180,0)` Не могу сказать, как правильно  `5(0,180,0)`  или так `5(0,180,180)` или так `5(0,0,180)`.

---

Ускорение. Так как кубик безсмысленно крутить одну сторону влево-вправо и т.п., можно добаить в цикл на 12 условия запрещающие это делать. Например, так

```
   if (level >= 2) /*then*/ {
      if (( a[a[i].prev].turn & 14 ) == (turn & 14)) /*then*/{ 
         // Если предыдущую грань двигали  ту же самую
         if (a[a[i].prev].turn != turn )  /*then*/
            continue; //Если Если предыдущую грань двигали в другую сторону
         // то не рассматриваем дальше, убрать туда-сюда движение
         // сюда код прийдёт, если более одного раза двигаем одну грань   
         if (a[a[a[i].prev].prev].turn == turn)
            continue; // Запрет поворачивать третий раз куб в одну сторону                      
      }
```

Т.е. в итоге алгоритм будет такой.

1. Задаём начальное условие
2. Начало итераций, цикл на 12 движений
3. Проверяем условия на лишние движения, если такие есть — переходим на 2.
4. Выполняем движение, готовим a`
5. Проверяем "граничное условие" что кубик "собран". Если собран — решение найдено.
6. Проверяем что а' отсутствует в массиве а. Если присутствует — к п 2.
7. добавляем а' в массив, и переходим к 2.
8. По завершению цикла создаём ещё одну итерацию.

Почитав про кубик-рубика в википедии, я нашел запись, что за 20 ходов можно найти решение. Возможно, более эффективным будет поиск вглубину с ограничением на 20. Для такого поиска нужен будет массив на 20, а не на несколько тысяч, как в этом варианте.

Comment: 2D-модель с массивом на 54 элемента у меня была в первой версии, там объектом была наклейка, и это всё работало, кстати! Теперь я перешёл к 3D-модели и элементов в массиве стало 26 (просто у них появились свойства о расположении наклеек на гранях), работать всё стало в 2 раза быстрее (т.к. при повороте нужно перемещать меньшее количество элементов), но 2D проекция сломалась. 
Огромный минус вашего предложения в том, что мы брутим данные, которые у нас и так на входе имеются. Это мало того, что лишнее, но и очень понизит общую производительность. Это в общем последнее о чём я думал.

Comment: думал об этом тоже, но это лишняя нагрузка, т.к. мы при  каждом повороте будем вынуждены вращать не только объект, но и расположение наклеек на нём, которые и так вращаются вместе с ним и должны однозначно определяться из вектора вращения и исходного и конечного положений, так же?

Comment: что вы понимаете под "вращением рисунка"?  
так всё определено, все правила заданы, всё отлажено и вращается со скоростью около чуть больше 10млн поворотов в секунду. Т.е. массив есть, данные в нём правильные, имеем исходное состояние каждого объекта, конечное и вектор поворота (самих движений нет). Речь только о визуализации.

Comment: так в вопросе вся конкретика, не рабочая во всём алгоритме 1 функция, которая имеет на входе данные о исходном и конечном положении (3D координаты и угол разворота вокруг каждой из осей) и, допустим, положение наклейки в исходном положении. Она должна дать ответ, где наклейка в конечном положении... т.е. если была вверху, то стала спереди и всё, проблема будет решена)

Comment: В общем то 6, но это не важно. Встречный вопрос: почему этот "байт вращения" должен отличаться от вращения основного элемента, которое уже есть на входе? Все наклейки поворачиваются вместе с ним и уголы поворота у всех одинаковы! Так для чего его отдельно ещё раз считать?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79684/discussion-between-isaev-and-nick-n-a).

Comment: Очень может быть, что я ошибаюсь, но я пока не понял в чём именно) в исходном/начальном положении, когда куб собран, каждая наклейка имеет углы поворота (0,0,0) так? вариантов конечно 24, но приклеены они жёстко и относительно друг друга не вращаются, потому нам в принципе нужно знать только положение одной из них, ибо обход сторон тоже сохраняется и последовательность неизменна. И поворот основного блока будет повторять повороты всех наклеек. Так?

Comment: Да. В 2Д модели положения будет 4-ре комбинации. Углы поворота... э... сильно сложно. И повороты нужно учесть. А уже в зависимости от выбора процедуры рендеринга, будет понятно нужно ли учитытывать сторону куба. Если да, то станет 24 комбинации, если нет - останется 4-ре комбинации. Я думаю лучше опрерировать числом 1..4 чем 3-Д вектором (6 чисел). Можно задать положение 3-Д вектором, но тогда вам прийдётся делать 20-ть операций поворота с помощью 5-ти 3-Д матриц перехода... оно вам надо? Если да - я опишу.

Comment: "Но проще, думаю, сделать 2D проекцию, и правильно её спроэцировать на 3D пространство." да так и было, в целях оптимизации проект перелопачен и действительно стало всё пошустрее...  и чисто теоретически 3D проекцию правильно спроецировать на 2D пространство должно быть ничуть не сложнее)

Comment: я плюсану ответ ибо никто больше не осмелился предложить альтернативу. Массив на 54, навеян википедией скорее всего, как и мне изначально, но это был плохой вариант, потому от наклейки, как объекта я избавился и назад не вернусь) Ответ хороший, но далеко не оптимальный и много лишнего, скорее всего кубик никогда просто не крутил серьёзно, а подошёл к проблеме влоб. Я попробую из него что-то подчерпнуть, чтобы найти в чём именно я заблудился, но если будет предложен альтернативный подход, может передумаю) И за хорошие объяснения тоже thanks

Comment: Нет, не читал википедию. Я решал задачи с поиском в ширину. Очень запомнилось "заливка экрана". Там поиск вглубину даёт переполнение стека. А вширину - хорошо работает. Делал поиск кратчайшего пути через поиск в ширину. Решал простые и олимпиадные комбинаторные задачи. Поэтому это первое что пришло в голову, а опыт позволяет быстро набросать ответ). Иногда в некоторых задачах эффективен поиск вглубину, если извесно что результат можно получить не более чем за 10 шагов. Я кубик серьёзно не крутил - но видел что некоторые знают его "секрет".Может теперь куплю)Напишите когда получится снаклейками

Answer (score 1):

Может кому пригодится:
"Правильное" решение было найдено с помощью кватернионов. Если не нужно плавное вращение каждой грани, а достаточно фиксированных поворотов (как в 2х-мерной развёртке), то вполне достаточно таблички из единичных кватернионов. Они описывают все возможные значения поворотом и обладают приятным преимуществом перед матричными вращениями: перемножаясь бесконечно переходят друг в друга не попадая в так называемые "шарнирные замки". Для плавной 3д-анимации потом так же просто интерполируются между кватернионами конечных положений.
Так же, в качестве оптимизации, была сгенерирована таблица их целочисленного умножения, чтобы не резать производительность плавающей арифметикой и не накапливать ошибку вычислений.
В результате общее время работы практически не пострадало (добавилось 2 сек на 100млн комбинаций)